# System-wide audio ducking

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

When using my speakers (connected via a receiver, which is connected to my computer via HDMI), Windows ducks the audio in every program - meaning when it detects vocals of any kind, it tries to lower the volume of the detected voice (which is usually the opposite of ducking). The problem only occurs on my speaker system, not my headphones. Here are the steps I have taken so far (copied from my unanswered Reddit post):

I have checked about 50 times under the communications tab to ensure it is set to 'do nothing'. I have quit out of every application and closed every background task I can think of (including Steam, Discord, Spotify, antivirus, etc.). I have restarted my computer several times. I have ran the audio troubleshooter several times as well. I also tried unplugging and re-plugging all HDMI cables from my computer and my receiver. Finally, I completely reinstalled my graphics driver.

If anyone can help with this problem it would be highly appreciated. I don't like having to use my headphones to hear anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click speakers icon in taskbar > Playback devices

Right-click your speakers > Properties

Enhancements tab, uncheck `Loudness equalization`

This is the solution for this problem on Windows 8.1. I'm assuming/hoping it's the same for your Win 10